# Laravel validation testing using data provider

Tags: php, laravel, validation, testing, phpunit

I have laravel rules validation and i want test it all give rules with one method and dataProvider using phpunit

For example i have rules `required|string|max:255` i want test `required` `string and`max:255` rules without writing test method separately

But i only can do it for `required` rules only i want test the second rules like `digit_between` for identity field but `first_name` field doesnt have `digit_between` but is `string`

1. here my example rules code

```
    {
     return [
      'identity_number' => 'required|digits_between:1,255|unique:borrowers',
      'first_name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
      'last_name'       => 'required|string|max:255',
      'birthdate'       => 'required|date',
     ];
    }
```

2.testing code :

```
    /**
     * Test store validation.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @group user
     * @dataProvider requiredStoreValidationProvider
     */
    public function testStoreValidation($formInput, $formInputValue)
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)
            ->post(route('borrower.store'), [
                $formInput => $formInputValue,
            ]);

        $response->assertSessionHasErrorsIn('validation', $formInput);
    }

    /**
     * Required store data validation provider.
     *
     * @return \string[][]
     */
    public function requiredStoreValidationProvider()
    {
        return [
            ['identity_number', ''],
            ['first_name', ''],
            ['last_name', ''],
            ['birthdate', ''],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each index is a one test scenario, So the first scenario is to test the required validation,
the second scenario would be digits_between:1,255, We set 256 for identity_number, because you have defined a range number, and the rest as you can see.

```
/**
     * Required store data validation provider.
     *
     * @return \string[][]
     */
    public function requiredStoreValidationProvider()
    {
        return [
            ['identity_number', ''],
            ['identity_number', 256],
            ['first_name', ''],
            ['first_name', 123],
            ['first_name', str_random(256)],
            ['last_name', ''],
            ['last_name', 123],
            ['last_name', str_random(256)],
            ['birthdate', ''],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: i have tried it and its work...

but can i also assert if on laravel errors session has key with translated message?

thanks :-D

Comment: You can pass $key, $value to $this->assertSessionHasErrors('validation', ['identity_number'=>'Your translated message']);

Comment: but it is work if i use `validation.php` translation file while in that file has `:attribute` `:max` `:min` and other parameter ?

Comment: It’ll work if you somehow parse it, i mean replace :attribute with the field name, max and min also. Then you’ll have a message which you can assert against the response. I think you can search for how laravel parse the validation message and use that otherwise you can just write your parser.

Comment: i know how laravel validation replace the parameter..i think i can pass it automatically without replace the attribute... but cant.. must replace it manually  thanks again for help me